# Gradle build results

Tags: java, gradle

I'm using Gradle to build my software. However, I find the output it proceduces a bit to minimal. I don't want to use --debug or --info, since that logging is much to verbose. I just want to know what the result in terms of artifacts (zip, jar, dmg, etc) of the Gradle buid is. For example, when I run 'gradle jar', I'd like to print where the jar is created.

I did that using:

```
jar {
    doLast {
        println "Jar has been created in ${archivePath}"
    }
}
```

And it nicely prints that the jar has been created in the build/lib directory. However, when I run 'gradle distZip', the artifact is not created in the lib dir, but in the distributions directory. The above however is still printed, but I'd rather not have that: when I run the distZip, I'd like to know where I can find the output of that command, not of every step the distZip depends on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, the following will work just nicely:

```
def artifacts = []

addListener(new TaskExecutionListener() {
    void afterExecute(Task task, TaskState state) {

            if(task in AbstractArchiveTask) {
                    artifacts << task.outputs.files.singleFile
            }
    }

    void beforeExecute(Task task) { }
})

addBuildListener(new BuildAdapter() {
    void buildFinished(BuildResult result) {
            if(artifacts) {
                    println "\nOutput location: ${artifacts.last()}\n"
            }
    }
})
```

This is also available as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/bodiam/5999047).